# The Frechet Derivative of the usual Functional $\int_a^b F(t,y,y')dt$ in Calculus of Variations

Tags: calculus-of-variations, frechet-derivative

My question concerns a step from the following derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation, from the standard book on calculus of variations by Gelfand and Fomin

[image]

While I understand the general procedure, I'm not sure why the integral of the reminder goes to zero. I've see other more general derivations of the Euler-Lagrange equation but they use more machinery from calculus over Banach spaces, so I'm trying to do this specific in $\mathbb R^3$ which uses more elementary calculus methods.

Reformulating my question more precisely, let's assume $F: \mathbb R ^3 \to \mathbb R$ is $C^2$ everywhere. By Taylor's formula, 
$$F(a+h_1, b+h_2, c+h_3) = F(a,b,c) + \langle \nabla F(a,b,c),(h_1,h_2,h_3)\rangle + R(h_1,h_2,h_3),$$
where we have the usual inner product in $\mathbb R^3$ and $R$ is the Taylor reminder, with $R(h_1, h_2, h_3)/\|(h_1,h_2, h_3)\|_{\mathbb R^3} \to 0$ as $(h_1,h_2,h_3) \to 0$ for a norm $\|\cdot\|_{\mathbb R^3}$ of $\mathbb R^3.$

By defining the functional J : $C^1([a,b], \mathbb R) \to \mathbb R,$ 
$$ y \in C^1([a,b],\mathbb R) \mapsto J(y) =  \int_a^b F(t,y(t),y'(t))dt$$
  the idea is to show that 
$$D J_y(h) =  \int_a^b [F_y(t,y(t),y'(t))h(t) + F_{z}(t,y(t),y'(t))h'(t)]dt $$ 
(where $F_y$ and $F_z$ denote the partial derivatives of $F$ with respect to the second and third coordinates) is the Frechet derivative of $J.$ Now the text is a bit vague but I believe this has to be done over the norm in $C^1([a,b], \mathbb R)$ given by $\|h\|_{C^1} = \sup_{[a,b]} |h(x)| + \sup_{[a,b]} |h'(x)|.$ What we must prove is that
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{J(y+h) - J(y) - DJ_y(h)}{\|h\|_{C^1}} = 0 $$
(where {$h \to 0$ means convergence on its norm). So, by applying Taylor's formula for $(0, h(t), h'(t)),$ we get
$$ F(t,y(t) + h(t), y'(t)+ h'(t)) = F(t,y(t),y'(t)) + F_y(t,y(t),y'(t))h(t) + F_z(t,y(t),y'(t))h'(t) + R(0,h(t),h'(t)), \quad \text{for each } t\in[a,b] $$ 
integrating and rearanging, I must prove
$$ \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\int^b_a R(0,h(t),h'(t))dt}{\|h\|_{C^1}} = 0$$

While this seems to be intuitively true since at each point $R$ is "small" compared to $h,$ I'm not sure how to precisely prove this last step. The integral and the norm are complicating my analysis.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What norm are you using?

Comment: On the domain of $J$ I'm taking the $C^1$ norm, and in the image $\mathbb R$ it is the usual absolute value.

Comment: Meaning something like $\|x\| =\|x\|_\infty + \|x'\|_\infty$?

Comment: Yes, precisely.